# How can I store a Backslash character in a String variable?

Tags: java, character

I'm trying to escape the character `\` in a String variable.

I've tried all escape methods I know of for special characters, but nothing works:

-use the  backslash `\`

-use the `\Q` and `\E`

-use the `Pattern.quote(String)` Method

Every time I try it my IDE `Eclipse` says that I need to finish the String with `"` quotes (I've already put those quotes, but I think that means `java` stills recognize my `\` character as a special code)

Any help to escape that `\` character?

Comment: You say you've used the backslash - do you mean you've used it as an escape character for another backslash, or do you mean you've used it alone? You need to use two backslashes in a Java string literal to have the variable contain one backslash. See "Escape Sequences" [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: i've used as an scape character for another backslash.

Comment: Use: \\ for one unescaped backslash.

Comment: So in other words: `String myString = "Here is a single backslash (\\) and here is a double backslash (\\\\)";`.